# Bitbucket won't trigger Jenkins build on commit when using a POST hook

Tags: jenkins, hook, bitbucket

I'm struggling with getting Bitbucket to POST to Jenkins in order to trigger my tests. I've tried the following without any success:

1. Bitbucket Jenkins Plugin
2. Jenkins Hook in Bitbucket
3. POST Hook in Bitbucket

I'm starting to suspect that the problem may be that I have spaces in the Jenkins job name although I'm not sure if this is actually the problem. The strange thing is that if try the same URI defined as "POST Hook" in Bitbucket from Postman it works! Here's a URI that works from Postman:

```
http://bitbucket:password@my-jenkins-server:8080/job/Integration%20Tests/build?token=ABCDEF
```

But it won't work if I paste it as a POST hook in bitbucket:

[image: BitBucket setup]

I've tried removing `%20` in case BitBucket URL encodes the URI  automatically but without success. Any clues?